# What do these color-index CSS media queries mean?

Tags: css, media-queries

What does the following values mean below?

```
screen and (color-index: 256) //value 1
screen, (color-index: 256) //value 2
(color-index: 256) //value 3
```

Comment: Your question needs a more descriptive title. Actually specify what your question in the title!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Value 3 is the simplest one: `(color-index: 256)` matches any device with 256 colors.

Value 1 combines that with the more common `screen` medium, so you're only matching screens with 256 colors (as opposed to, say, audio readers where "256 colors" is a nonsensical thing to look for anyway).

And Value 2 has a comma, which is recognizable from other aspects of CSS. We might write `p, h1 { color: purple; }` indicating that if an element is either a `p` OR an `h1` the rule applies. Here it's a device that's a `screen` or has 256 colors.

You may find https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Media_queries instructive.